# Reload Div after ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax

been trying to solve this but not having much luck

I have a todo list which has a flag and trash. When you load the page I can add a todo and it shows on the list without refreshing the back. 
Problem one is when i try to add the second item it reloads the page and doesn't add the item. 
Problem two is if you don't add a another todo after the first the flag and trash scripts don't work.

See code below. I am trying to be able to add and delete and flag a todo without having to refresh the page.

.js file

```
    //To Do list flag item. Change color of text when Flag button is clicked and change back when flag button is pressed again.
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".flag" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).closest(".todo-list-item").attr('id')
    var theid = ('#' + id);
    $(theid).toggleClass('todo-list-item-flagged');
     event.stopPropagation();
});
});


// Delete Task from database. This will delete the row in the database and remove the line from the page without page refresh

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".trash").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   var id = $(this).closest(".todo-list-item").attr('id');
   var $ele = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'functions/removetask.php',
    data:{id:id},
    success: function(data){
         if(data=="YES"){
             $ele.fadeOut().remove();
         }else{
             alert("can't delete the row")
         }
    }

     });
      event.stopPropagation();
});
});

// Add task to database without page refresh


$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btn-task').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'addtask.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                $("#todo-list").load(location.href+"  #todo-list>*","");
            }
          });

        });
});
```

.html file (Cut down to just the area I am trying to fix)

```
    <div id="todos">
        <div id="todo-list" class="panel panel-blue">
            <div class="panel-heading dark-overlay"><svg class="glyph stroked clipboard-with-paper"><use xlink:href="#stroked-clipboard-with-paper"></use></svg>To-do List</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul  class="todo-list">
                 <?php
                        include'connect.php';
                        $query = $_SESSION['user'];
                        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT uname FROM tbl_users WHERE userId='$query'");
                        $name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                        $uname = $name['uname'];

                        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM tbl_todo WHERE uname='$uname'");
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                            ?>
                                <li id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="todo-list-item"><label><?php echo $row['task']; ?></label>
                                    <div class="pull-right action-buttons">
                                        <a href="#"class="edit"><svg class="glyph stroked pencil"><use xlink:href="#stroked-pencil"></use></svg></a>
                                        <a  class="flag"><svg class="glyph stroked flag"><use xlink:href="#stroked-flag"></use></svg></a>
                                        <a id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="trash"><svg class="glyph stroked trash"><use xlink:href="#stroked-trash"></use></svg></a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                        <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
            <form id="todo" method="POST" action"#">

                    <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="uname" name="uname" type="text" class="hidden form-control input-md" placeholder="Add new task" value="<?php echo userLogin('uname');?>" />
                    <input id="task" name="task" type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Add new task" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-task" >Add</button>
                    </span>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

There is no validation yet of user input. I shall be adding this in when I know the scripts work then I will add in validation. All help is much appreciated. I'm a newbie but trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

So I have worked out where I was going wrong. My whole issue was because I was using dynamically added id. The way in which I was using the selectors was incorrect. I shall now show you which selectors I have to change to what the issue was that it solved.

1. Reload the whole page on trying to add the second Item.

Original Selector

```
 $('.btn-task').click(function (e)
```

Updated Selector

```
 $('#todo-list').submit(function (e)
```

2. After Adding an Item Trash script would not work.

Original Selector

```
  $(".trash").click(function(e)
```

Updated Selector

```
 $('#todo-list').on('click','.trash', function(e)
```

3. After adding an item flag script would not work.

Original Selector

```
$( ".flag" ).click(function(e)
```

Updated Selector

```
$( '#todo-list' ).on('click','a',function(e)
```

I hope this answer helps other people in the future. This is purely a newbie mistake. I'm sure a more experienced person would not make this mistake.

My reference for this was from this article (post 5) [Sitepoint article](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/jquery-code-doesnt-work-on-dynamic-content-loaded-with-ajax/31758/5)